# what I do for show the accessorytype in custom(uilabel) uitableviewcell when cell contentcolor is black in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

what I do for show the accessorytype in custom(uilabel) uitableviewcell when cell contentcolor property is set to be black i want to show whole cell's color is black but when i use 
cell.accessoryType =[UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator through this i can't reach my target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to set the `accessoryView` property, which overrides (and therefore ignores) the `accessoryType` value.